# Login activity goes to next activity even if the condition is not true

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-volley

This is my code in which I am trying to move to Next activity which is **Dashboard** after user is authenticated it works well but it moves to next activity even if credentials are incorrect or wrong...

I have written if else condition for moving to next activity and not moving to next activity....
But still it moves to next activity I don't know why is this happening...

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.demo;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText etusername, etpassword;
    String username, password;
    FloatingActionButton loginbtn;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etusername = findViewById(R.id.etemail);
        etpassword = findViewById(R.id.etpw);
        loginbtn=findViewById(R.id.floatingloginButton);
        loginbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Output 1","Button clicked");
                loginverify();
            }
        });

    }

    private void loginverify() {
        username = etusername.getText().toString().trim();
        password = etpassword.getText().toString().trim();

        Log.d("Output 2","login verify Function called");
        if (username.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Username cannnot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("Output 3","if con 1");

            return;
        } else if (password.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Password cannnot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("Output 3","if con 2");
            return;
        }else{
            Log.d("Output 5","inside else");
            StringRequest request= new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "https://**url**/login.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                   // Log.d("Output 4",response);
                    if(!response.equalsIgnoreCase("Login Failed.......Try Again..")){
                        Log.d("Output 6","login failed");
     

               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Dashboard.class));
                 }else{
                    Log.d("Output 6","login passed");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   return;
                }

             //   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              //  startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Dashboard.class));
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("Response error",error.getMessage().toString());
            }
        }
        ){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("login_name",username);
            params.put("login_pass",password);
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

}
```

}

Below is my php code... Sorry for such a weak code...

```
<?php  
 require "../dbcn.php";  
 $user_name = $_POST["login_name"];  
 $user_pass =  $_POST["login_pass"];  
 $sql_query = "select Firstname,Lastname from users where emailid like '$user_name' and password like '$user_pass';";  
 $result = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql_query);  
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >0 )  
 {  
 $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);  
 $name =$row["Firstname"]." ".$row["Lastname"];  
 echo "Login Success..Welcome ".$name;  
 }  
 else  
 {   
 echo "Login Failed.......Try Again..";  
 }  
 ?>
```

Comment: This is the time to start using a debugger.

Comment: But you are using `Log` incorrectly in `OnResponse`; you are logging failed in first scope of your `if`

Comment: @HamidSj I am using not (!) to reverse the condition

Comment: @John you have `Log.d("Output 6","login failed");` if the response is 'not' equal to `Login Failed.......Try Again..`

I recommend to use `status_code` instead of message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

comparing `String` results is very, VERY wrong approach... besides that this `if` is also very improper

```
if(!response.equalsIgnoreCase("Login Failed.......Try Again..")){

}
```

so anything other that above `String` will open next `Activity`, e.g. when you change even a single character on server-side, or connection broke in the middle and you will get only half of `String`... (theoretically)

for letting user to some hidden/restricted area you should ALWAYS use positive, clearly stated condition, not opposite of deny... try with `if(response.startsWith("Login Success"))`, but still comparing `String`s isn't good idea... (thats why you got downvotes)

consider using some standard for formatting text, like XML or JSON, or just return some `int` codes, e.g. `0` for positive log in, `-1` password mismatch, `-2` user not found, etc. depends on your purposes. and of course as logged in condition use `if(result==0)`, not `!` of all other possible codes...

Answer (score 0):

I recommended you use JSON format inside onResponse method and use equals() instead of equalsIgnoreCase.OnResponse method takes some time depending upon your response data and internet speed. If you are use boolean value in response this is the best of condition.